# Possible to rename file and maintain undo?

Tags: save, undo-redo, persistent-state

Is there a way to rename/copy/move a file and maintain the vim persistent undo information?

If I do

```
:w new-file-name
```

and then

```
:e new-file-name
```

I can't hit <kbd>u</kbd> to undo. `Already at oldest change` :-(

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`:saveas`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Asaveas) keeps the undo history intact.

`:saveas` is equivalent to the combination of `:w newname` followed by `:e #`. I usually find it more handy than the `:w` + `:e`, especially since with `:saveas` it's not really possible to *forget* about doing the second command and end up editing the first file. (Which you can guess is something I've done more than once!)

Answer (score 1):

Tim Pope created [eunuch plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) with such feature. It has `:Move` and `:Rename` commands. Do not know if it works under Windows since description is about UNIX shell commands, can't test it right now. Also as filbranden said you can copy with `:saveas`.